# Using integer declaration instead of pointer integer when pointer swaping in C language

Tags: c, pointers, integer, swap, dereference

I have seen many articles discussing `pointer swapping`, in many of them, they use this code:

```
void ptr_swap(int **p1, int **p2)
{
     int *temp = *p1;
     *p1 = *p2;
     *p2 = temp;      
}
```

but I am not clear as to why it is necessary to declare temp as a pointer rather than as a natural integer. When I tested it, it did not make any difference.

```
void ptr_swap(int **p1, int **p2)
{
    int temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Save time, enable all warnings to quickly see trouble with `int **p1 ... int temp = *p1;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the type of `*p1` is `int*`. This type is not compatible with `int` and a cast would be required. Moreover, the cast itself is implementation defined and `int` may not be long enough to store a value of a pointer without loosing bits.

It will likely fail on 64-bit machine where pointers are 64-bit-long and `int` is 32-bit-long.

Btw consider using the macro below to implement `swap` operation that works with any type and provides type checking:

```
#define SWAP(a,b)                      \
  do {                                 \
    char tmp__[sizeof(a)];             \
    void *va__ = &(a);                 \
    void *vb__ = &(b);                 \
    (void)sizeof(&(a) - &(b));         \
    memcpy(tmp__, va__, sizeof tmp__); \
    memcpy( va__, vb__, sizeof tmp__); \
    memcpy(vb__, tmp__, sizeof tmp__); \
  } while (0)
```

Comment: Thank you. The answer is very informative. To be certain, does the reason it works in my environment have to do with computer bits/compilers/etc?.

Comment: @chqrlie, see the updated answer

Comment: @AvishaiDotan, probably because the 32-higher bits in values of pointer are only 0s or 1s. However it is a pure accident. If you want to cast a pointer to an integer then use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`

Comment: @AvishaiDotan: yes, the reason it works on your environment is a combination of: pointers having the same size as `int` (typical in 32-bit operating systems), disregard for compiler warnings and/or permissive compiler settings, pure luck...

Comment: @chqrlie, AFAIK, two `_` are reserved. However one underscore is fine.

Comment: @tstanisl AFAIK underscores at the _end_  of an identifier are not reserved.

Comment: @chqrlie, there is no need for it, `char(*)[10]` and `char(*)[12]` are not compatible. Moreover GCC allows 0-sized arrays and it will likely raise no warning

Comment: Good point! `(void)sizeof(&(a) - &(b));` is sufficient... Note however that `&(a) - &(b)` has undefined behavior if `a` and `b` are not part of the same array. Only `!=` and `==` are defined but would only produce a diagnostic, not an error.

Comment: @chqrlie, it would be UB only if the expression is *evaluated*. However the operand of `sizeof` is never evaluated

Comment: @chqrlie, what do think about `char tmp__[sizeof(&(a) - &(b)) ? sizeof(a) : -1];` ?

Comment: This expression might cause a warning because of the implicit conversion of `-1` to `size_t`. Why not use `0`?

Comment: @chqrlie, Probably is doesn't matter what is there at all. This branch is never evaluated because the condition operand `sizeof(&(a) - &(b))` is a non-zero constant integer expression.

Comment: @tstanisl The role is `(void)sizeof(&(a) - &(b));` is unclear.  Please elaborate.  Seems all it is doing is finding the size of a pointer difference, which is then discarded.

Comment: The branch is never evaluated of course, but the constraints are verified.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: `sizeof(&(a) - &(b))` is a consistency test that will produce an error if the types of `a` and `b` are not compatible.

Comment: @chqrlie Hmmm. The difference of two pointers is a `ptrdiff_t`.  `sizeof(&(a) - &(b))` is simply the same as `sizeof(ptrdiff_t)`.  What _consistency test_ do you see here should type differ?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: the expression `&(a) - &(b)` will not compile if the types of `a` and `b` are not compatible, ie: if the macro is invoked on variables of different types.